# How i can use latest mui with preact?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, preact

I wanna use mui with preact but preact does not support mui.Is there a way to use mui with preact.

I used a package called preact-mui but it is also out dated and not functioning properly.
Is there any way to use mui with preact? I dont wanna use material design.

Comment: It would be MUI not supporting Preact, not the other way around. But what do you think isn't supported? They seem to have an official example set up showcasing usage: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/preact

Comment: The link posted by @rschristian has changed. Here's the new one: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-preact

Comment: Changed once more https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-preact